# Using a variable in place of a string

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to both JS and React and I'm working on a project for a bootcamp. I'm collaborating on a chat app and I wanted some insight on replacing strings with a variable to clean up the code. Here's what I'm working on:

```
import React from 'react';

const Form = React.createClass({

  submit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.messagesRef.push({
      text: this.refs.text.value,
      time: Date.now(),
      user: {
        displayName: this.props.user.displayName,
        photoURL: this.props.user.photoURL,
        uid: this.props.user.uid,
      },
    });
    this.refs.text.value = '';
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <form className="form" onSubmit={this.submit}>
    <input className="form-input" placeholder="Write     something…" ref="text"/>
        <button className="form-button">Send</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
});
export default Form;
```

I'd like to replace `this.refs.text.value` with a variable so I can clean up the code, but I'm not really sure how. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What's the problem with `this.ref.text.value`?

Comment: there's no problem with it, I just want to learn how to replace it with a variable

Comment: You mean like this: `var val = this.ref.text.value;`? And then: `text: val`

Comment: exactly. However i'm such a react noob i'm not sure where in the code I would put the variable haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use a variable to store the value and use it in place of `this.refs.text.value`:

```
submit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var val = this.refs.text.value;

  this.props.messagesRef.push({
    text: val, //notice the use of val
    time: Date.now(),
    user: {
      displayName: this.props.user.displayName,
      photoURL: this.props.user.photoURL,
      uid: this.props.user.uid,
    },
  });
  this.refs.text.value = ''; //do not use val here!
},
```

This just uses a variable `val` in place of `this.refs.text.value`, although *I would not recommend it* because it doesn't necessarily make the code *cleaner*. Make sure *not to change* `this.refs.text.value = '';` because if you do, you'll be reassigning the reference which is incorrect.

Comment: Much appreciated Andrew!

Comment: No problem @TylerSchmidt if I did help please consider accepting the answer :)